# How to check rowwise condition for a data frame (with dplyr, purrr, etc)?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, purrr

I have a data frame and I want to generate a variable that for each row tells if all the elements of a certain subset of variables are equal to a given element or not.

In the next example, the `new` variable should be `TRUE` for the rows with `y` and `z` equal to `1`, and `FALSE` otherwise. But the result is all `FALSE`. I made many changes in the code and tried to use `purrr::pmap.dbl` and `do.call`, but without success.

```
library(dplyr)
test <- data.frame(x=c(0,1,1), y = c(1,1,1), z = c(1,1,0))
test %>% mutate(new = all(select(.,-x) == 1))
  x y z   new
1 0 1 1 FALSE
2 1 1 1 FALSE
3 1 1 0 FALSE
```

It is understood that it is a simple example, but I have many more variables, I have to use `select` and `all` or something similar, and the specific element is not `1`.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, but is it possible to make condition independent on number of variables? Why `all` does not work? Thank you!

Comment: I think this should be something like `rowSums(test[-1] == 1) == ncol(test[-1])` as you need to compare all of the cols to 1 first. Though it is probably better to predefine the columns you want to use and then create some robust function that just use those cols, something like `f <- function(data, cols, value) rowSums(data[cols] == value) == length(cols)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Currently I would do:

```r
library(tidyverse)
all_cols <- function(df) reduce(df, `&`)
test %>% 
    mutate(new = all_cols(across(-x,~`==`(.,1))))
```

**Old**

I think I have found a solution to the problem:

```
test %>% 
  mutate(new = 
    purrr::pmap(mutate_at(., vars(-x), `==`, 1) %>% select(-x), all) %>% 
    unlist())
```

The problem of what I tested in the question seems to be that the output of `select(.,-x) == 1` is not a data frame but a matrix...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
test %>% mutate(new = y&z)
```

Works with other values than 0/1

Answer (score 0):

I've added other features in the data frame you gave as an example. I believe the only condition you want to check or ensure is `y` and `z` to be equal to `1` at the same time `&`.

```r
test %>% mutate(new = ifelse((y ==1 & z==1),TRUE,FALSE))
```

## Data

```r
structure(list(x = c(0, 1, 1, 2), y = c(1, 1, 1, 2), z = c(1, 
1, 0, 2), d = c(0, 0, 0, 2), e = c(1, 2, 2, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: or `test %>% mutate(new = y == 1 & z == 1)`

Answer (score 0):

A data.table solution:

```
setDT(test)[y == 1 & z == 1, new := TRUE]
```

Will give you `TRUE` when the condition met and `NA` otherwise. If you need `FALSE`, then:

```
setDT(test)[, new := FALSE]
test[y ==1 & z ==1, new := TRUE]
```